# Can a game be conducted with 30 second per move. And if the player finishes 30 seconds the move goes to the other player

Tags: online-chess

I am currently participating in a chess competition and they have kept the timer as 30 seconds per move. If you cannot move within 30 seconds, the move gets passed on to the other player. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are participating in it, doesn't that prove that it is possible?

Comment: In case of a double zugzwang, the tournament will last until the end of times...

Comment: Likewise K+R vs. K is a draw.

Comment: One possible rule that needs to be added is that if no move has been played during the last minute, then you have to make a move in the next 30", otherwise you lose on time. Said otherwise, you are allowed to pass only once if your opponent does the same.

Answer (score 3):

No. Then there would be no Zugzwang. Zugzwang would mean draw.
This type of time control removes a very important concept in chess and thus reduces the depth and beauty of the game.

Comment: What if the rule were that if player X doesn't move within 30 seconds, player Y has 30 seconds to choose what move player X must play in addition to his own response?  In most situations, player Y would be able to pick a fatally bad move for player X and then exploit it, but if e.g. player X is up with a queen and knight against a lone knight, player Y would probably not be able to do anything worse than make player X drop a queen (leading to a draw by lack of mating material) even though given enough "helpmate" turns the player with the lone knight could checkmate the other player.

Comment: So there is no zugzwang? That's a shame, but doesn't keep it from being a viable variation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible because with the move being given to the opposing player, they could take that move to their advantage and get you into a checkmate. I believe that this type of variation is interesting and very possible.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like an interesting variation and possible. 3 fold repetition would make a null move after 30 seconds followed by other null moves end in tie.